# complex preprocessor symbol for ede project

Tags: preprocessor, emacs24, cedet

I don't know how to write the spp-table entries for those defines:

```
#define FUNC(rettype, memclass) rettype

#define VAR(type, memclass) type
```

Could you help me to add it in my following ede-cpp-root-project configuration.

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "sample"
            :name "sample_ede"
            :file "~/Dropbox/emacs/sample_projet/base.ede"
            :include-path '("/"
                            "/Mod1/inc"
                            "/Mod2/inc"
                            "/ModAutosar/inc"
                            "/autosar"
            )
            :spp-table '(
                        ("AUTOMATIC" . "")
                        ("TYPEDEF" . "")
                        ("_INTERRUPT_" . "__interrup")
                        ("INLINE" . "inlince")
                        )       
             )
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add complex macros into your preprocessor table is to create a source file.  For example, stick the two lines of code you quote in you question into edeconfig.h at the root of your project.  Then add the configuration:

:spp-files '( "edeconfig.h" )

into your `ede-cpp-root-project`.  That will then create the correct entries without having to learn the spp syntax.

If you feel daring, you could visit said file, and type:

```
M-x semantic-lex-spp-describe RET
```

And look for:

```
FUNC        ((spp-arg-list ("rettype" "memclass") 13 . 32) (symbol "rettype" 33 . 40))
VAR     ((spp-arg-list ("type" "memclass") 53 . 69) (symbol "type" 70 . 74))
```

and copy that in.